# Can't pre-populate Django database

Tags: python, django, django-models, backend

So I've been following this guide from Django 1.1 but I'm actually using Django 2 for how to pre-populate Django database I'm using SQLite database and this is my code with Faker library but it just won't run when I want to run it in the CMD.

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'first_project.settings')

import django
django.setup()

## FAKE POPULATION SCRIPT:

import random
from first_app.models import AccessRecord,Webpage,Topic
from faker import Faker

# Creating a fake generator:
fakegen = Faker()
topics = 

['Search', 'Social', 'Marketplace', 'News', 'Games']
def add_topic():
    t = Topic.objects.get_or_create(top_name=random.choice(topics))[0]
    t.save()
    return t

def populate(N = 5):

for entry in range(N):

    # GET THE TOPIC FOR THE ENTRY:
    top = add_topic()

    # Create the fake data for that entry:
    fake_url = fakegen.url()
    fake_date = fakegen.date()
    fake_name = fakegen.company()

    # Create the new webpage entry:
    webpg = Webpage.objects.get_or_create(topic = top, url = fake_url, name = fake_name)[0]

    # Create a fake access record for that webpage
    acc_rec = AccessRecord.get_or_create(name = webpg, date = fake_date)[0]

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        print("Populating Script!")
        populate(20)
        print("Populating Complete!")
```

This is the `models.py` file of the only app I have in this project.

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Topic(models.Model):
    top_name = models.CharField(max_length=264, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.top_name

class Webpage(models.Model):
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=264,unique=True)
    url = models.URLField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class AccessRecord(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Webpage,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date)
```

And this is the error that I am getting

```
Populating script!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "populate_first_app.py", line 41, in <module>
    populate(20)
  File "populate_first_app.py", line 37, in populate
    acc_rec = AccessRecord.objects.get_or_create(name=webpg,date=fake_date)[0]
  File "C:\Users\divya\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\m

odels\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\divya\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\m
odels\query.py", line 559, in get_or_create
  File "C:\Users\divya\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1250, in build_filter
    lookups, parts, reffed_expression = self.solve_lookup_type(arg)
  File "C:\Users\divya\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1087, in solve_lookup_type
    _, field, _, lookup_parts = self.names_to_path(lookup_splitted, self.get_meta())
  File "C:\Users\divya\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1482, in names_to_path
    raise FieldError("Cannot resolve keyword '%s' into field. "
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'date' into field. Choices are: id, name, name_id
```

Comment: Did you check your migrations? It seems like **AccessRecord** table does not contain date field in the database. Also check your database for **date** field in **AccessRecord** table.

Answer (score 1):

Your error on the line: `date = models.DateField`.
Correct on `date = models.DateField()` and make migrations.